# Can't access object attributes from service in Angular Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory, promise, directive

I have a JSON service that outputs a roleName and an id and I am trying to use the role to hide or show elements in an application using an angular directive. It appears that the service is successfully being called and $scope.data is being populated from the output but I don't seem to be able to access the role from the data object as the console log reads Undefined for $scope.data.rolename.

**.JS**

```
app.directive('restrictTo', ['SecuritySvc', function (SecuritySvc) {
return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    scope: {},
    controller: ['$scope', '$attrs', '$q', 'SecuritySvc', function ($scope, $attrs, $q, SecuritySvc) {
        $scope.data = SecuritySvc.getRole();

            if ($scope.data.roleName == $attrs.restrictTo) {
                $scope.allowed = true;
            } else {
                $scope.allowed = false;
            }

            console.log($scope.data); // showing in log
            console.log($scope.data.roleName); // Undefined

    }],
    template: '<div ng-show="{{ $scope.allowed }}" ng-transclude></div>'
}
```

Console output from the code above

```
$promise: Object
$resolved: true
roleId: 1
roleName: "Admin"

undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I'm a little confused on your purpose here.  You are creating a deferred promise and then immediately resolving it?  Doesn't that defeat the purpose of the deferred/promise pattern's handling of asynchronous calls?  Is your `SecuritySvc.getRole()` method doing an AJAX call to return that data?  I had always thought that the AJAX call should be the thread calling `Promise::resolve` once it had completed.  Have you tried just using `$http`?

Even after all that, I'm REALLY confused that you can console.log `data` successfully, but not `data.roleName`.  `data` showing up implies that whatever you're doing with the deferred/promise pattern, you're getting your response where you need it.  Are you certain about the structure of the `data` object at this point?  There's no layer between `data` and your information?  I'm a little surprised to see it buried in with the Angular methods and properties like `$promise` and `$resolved`.

Don't know if any of that is helpful...

Comment: I cleaned it up and took the promise out which will hopefully make things a little clearer. The SecuritySvc.getRole(); works in a controller and I can display data.roleName but not in the directive.

Comment: @citizenslave I can see you that you've done your best to answer the question here, but in most cases it's best to get any clarification you need before you answer by adding a comment to the question.

Comment: @TwentyGotoTen, Thanks.  I will do that as soon as I have sufficient reputation, but I didn't realize that was the proper protocol anyway.  
---
@rlwheeler, that helps clear up your code a little bit, but could you rerun it like that and copy/paste the console results for the updated code?  Obviously the `$promise` and `$resolved` properties should be gone.  I'm still exceptionally confused, even with marfarma's response below, how you can log an object but not one of its members.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this behavior when your directive creates an isolated scope (as yours does) and the service is accessing the view controller (rather than the directive controller) scope.  Since the scopes are different, the `$scope.data` objects are different.

You can check the scope id numbers by placing a breakpoint within the directive controller and another within the service, and examine the $id values.  There are several ways of working around this, but the specific solution will depend on your particular implementation.

It might be helpful to read up on the isolated scope bindings - '@' and '=', see:

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive